# Is $SSE/(n−2)$  an estimator of the variance of the dependent variable for a fixed x-value?  

Tags: regression

For linear regression, is an estimator of the variance of the dependent variable for a fixed x-value $SSE/(n-2)$?

Comment: You are assuming one independent variable and a constant term, right?

Comment: @whuber : yes I am. Is it correct then? Thanks.

Comment: Technically any function of the data can be an estimator. Whether or not it is a good estimator is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you're looking for an estimate of the residual variance.  See e.g. [the wikipedia article on simple linear regression](/http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), though it's rather hidden there.  I'd suggest a trip to the library, or buy a copy of Freedman et al, [Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393929728).

Also note that this is about $\text{var}(y) \cdot (1 - r^2)$.

Comment: The estimator is for $\text{var}(y) \cdot (1-r^2)$? This is the same thing as the residual variance right?

Comment: @JamesErl Please register your account -- you will be able to post comments then. Just visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login .

Comment: @JamesErl The variance of y for a fixed x is another way of saying residual variance.

Comment: @Karl Broman: So RMSE is basically the standard deviation of the difference in means of 2 populations?

Comment: @Damien No, I don't think that's at all related.

Comment: @Karl Broman: RMSE is the standard deviation of y for a fixed x. If you do a t-test and look at the standard deviation of the difference in means it is the same as the RMSE. Maybe that is just a coincidence?

Comment: @Damien - but you said "standard deviation of the difference in means". Rather, the residual variance is the within-population variance. The correlation is not so meaningful for the binary x case, and so the formula with $(1-r^2)$ is not so meaningful for the comparison of the means of two populations.

Comment: @Damien Could you confirm that your the original poster? We could merge your two accounts on the present one (which is actually registered).